# How to make Cycles default?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

Is there a way to make Cycles Render the default in Blender instead of Blender Render? (I hope this hasn't been asked before.)

Comment: When you open blender, change to cycles and CTRL+U to save startup file

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here are the steps to do that.

- Open Blender.
- Change the Render Engine to Cycles in the pull down menu (top center)
- Then go to File - Save Startup File.

Thats it. Next time you start with a new file, it is gonna be Cycles Engine by default.